# Why does my RxJava Observable not complete?

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm trying to test this observable for a login request, but the subscribers onNext and onCompleted methods are never called.

```
return mDeviceRepository.getDeviceId()

            .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<LoginResponse>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<LoginResponse> call(String deviceId) {
                    return mAuthRepository.login(deviceId, mUsername, mHashedPassword);
                }
            })

            .flatMap(new Func1<LoginResponse, Observable<LoginResponse>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<LoginResponse> call(LoginResponse loginResponse) {
                    mSessionRepository.storeSession(UserSession.fromLoginReponse(loginResponse));
                    mUserRepository.storeUser(loginResponse.getUser());
                    return Observable.just(loginResponse);
                }
            });
```

My test looks like this:

```
loginUseCase.setCredentials("testuser", "testpassword");
when(mockDeviceRepository.getDeviceId()).thenReturn(Observable.just("testdeviceid"));
when(mockAuthRepository.login("testdeviceid", "testuser", "testpassword")).thenReturn(Observable.just(new LoginResponse()));

testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber();
loginUseCase.buildUseCaseObservable().toBlocking().subscribe(testSubscriber);

testSubscriber.assertCompleted();
testSubscriber.assertValueCount(1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about assertTerminalEvent() instead of assertCompleted() in TestSubscriber ? 
All of your operators operate on same thread, so if TestSubscriber assertions were reached, then exception was thrown somewhere in stream

Comment: I'm not getting any NullPointers. The login mehod is stubbed using mockito: when(mockAuthRepository.login("testdeviceid", "testuser", "testpassword")).thenReturn(Observable.just(new LoginResponse()));

Comment: You call mAuthRepository.login(deviceId, mUsername, mHashedPassword) - where do last two arguments come from ? Are they exactly "testuser", "testpassword"?

Comment: Those are member variables of the class creating the observable. I'm initializing them before stubbing the login method. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: replacing assertCompleted() with assertTerminalEvent() fails also?

Comment: You were right! I missed a nullpointer exception because the underlying user object of my loginResponse was empty. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: all operators in question operate on same thread, so if testSubscriber's assertions are reached, then exception is thrown in stream

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  loginUseCase.buildUseCaseObservable().subscribe(testSubscriber);
```

PS: If you want side effects, don't do them in a flatMap. Use a side effect operators e.g.

```
return mDeviceRepository.getDeviceId()
        .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<LoginResponse>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<LoginResponse> call(String deviceId) {
                return mAuthRepository.login(deviceId, mUsername, mHashedPassword);
            }
        })
        .doOnNext(new Action1<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void call(String loginResponse) {
                mSessionRepository.storeSession(UserSession.fromLoginReponse(loginResponse));
                mUserRepository.storeUser(loginResponse.getUser());                   
            }           
        })
        .flatMap(new Func1<LoginResponse, Observable<LoginResponse>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<LoginResponse> call(LoginResponse loginResponse) {

                return Observable.just(loginResponse);
            }
        });
```